# Download Remote XML file into Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to download a remote XML file *into* the extension package as a "database update"?  Is there a reference link or proven method for doing so?

I know that Ad-Blocker Plus has the ability to update easy filters. Is this the same concept? Any thoughts on how this is done?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `cross origin XHR`, if so yes it is possible.

Comment: @Sudarshan I've since been storing the data in the `localStorage`. I was unable to determine or figure the way to forcefully store the data  using `cross origin XMLHttpRequest` to a file within the extension package. It might yet prove useful if I'd figure it out. :)